# How programme a JavaScript app in Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a Javascript code for Mozilla Firefox which insert a link in different websites when they have a special condition. 
I was thinking to do an app to do the same in my Android mobile phone.
I have done an app which loads an URL and I can see this website in a webView.
Now, I would like to insert my JavaScript code with the intention of do the same but I do not how to do it.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle InstanceState)
     {
    super.onCreate(InstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    webBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webkit);
    webBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webBrowser.loadUrl("http://www.onekin.org");
         }
```

I have seen that I should use this function but it has been impossible to let it work

addJavascriptInterface(Object object, String name)

Does somebody know how I can do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using your own WebViewClient:

Define your link

```
private String link = "http://yourlink.html";
```

Adapt your code to something like:

```
webBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webBrowser.setWebViewClient(new TestWebViewClient());
webBrowser.loadUrl("http://www.onekin.org");
// Interface to inject your javascript
webBrowser.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "MYJSINTERFACE");
```

Interface looks something like:

```
class JavaScriptInterface {
    public void inject(String html) {
        // Here you will get the Javascript executed
    }
}
```

Where your client injects the JS:

```
private class TestWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override  
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        String javascript = "javascript:window.MYJSINTERFACE.inject(document.getElementById('yourlink').href = "+link+");";

        // Inject Javascript in the URL already loaded
        webBrowser.loadUrl(javascript);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your own class which contains the link your want to insert : 
[addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)).

```
 class JavascriptUrlObject {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String toString() { return "http://the-url-to-insert.com"; }
 }
 webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavascriptUrlObject (), "injectedObject");
 webView.loadData("", "text/html", null);
 webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(injectedObject.toString())");
```

In this example, it just opens an alert, but you can do what you want with it in your page.

Look at this link if it can help you : [Android addJavaScriptInterface - Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/392603/Android-addJavaScriptInterface).